# Oracle - Text Classification (adding a secondary column)

Tags: oracle, text-classification

I'm following the demo on training on classification from Oracle.

I've attached the script.

In what way can this be used to create multiple sets of rules based on a secondary column?  The column wouldn't be an extra predictor, but really a way to completely isolate the rules.

That column might have its own list of data, and I'd hate to create separate sets of tables to handle the scenario.

So for example, if I added a doc_type field to ml_docs (and to the categories).  When its 1 I might want to use one set of rules and if its a 2, a different set of rules.  I want them to be completely isolated.  What implications would that have on the script?  Does Oracle support this?

```
create table ml_docs (
  doc_id number primary key,
  doc_text   clob);

insert into ml_docs values
(1, 'MacTavishes is a fast-food chain specializing in burgers, fries and -
shakes. Burgers are clearly their most important line.');
insert into ml_docs values
(2, 'Burger Prince are an up-market chain of burger shops, who sell burgers -
and fries in competition with the likes of MacTavishes.');
insert into ml_docs values
(3, 'Shakes 2 Go are a new venture in the low-cost restaurant arena, 
specializing in semi-liquid frozen fruit-flavored vegetable oil products.');
insert into ml_docs values
(4, 'TCP/IP network engineers generally need to know about routers, 
firewalls, hosts, patch cables networking etc');
insert into ml_docs values
(5, 'Firewalls are used to protect a network from attack by remote hosts,
 generally across TCP/IP');


create table ml_category_descriptions (
  cd_category    number,
  cd_description varchar2(80));

create table ml_doc_categories (
  dc_category    number,
  dc_doc_id      number,
  primary key (dc_category, dc_doc_id)) 
  organization index;

-- descriptons for categories

insert into ml_category_descriptions values (1, 'fast food');
insert into ml_category_descriptions values (2, 'computer networking');

insert into ml_doc_categories values (1, 1);
insert into ml_doc_categories values (1, 2);
insert into ml_doc_categories values (1, 3);
insert into ml_doc_categories values (2, 4);
insert into ml_doc_categories values (2, 5);

exec ctx_ddl.create_preference('bid_lex', 'basic_lexer');
exec ctx_ddl.set_attribute    ('bid_lex', 'index_themes', 'no');
exec ctx_ddl.set_attribute    ('bid_lex', 'index_text',   'yes');

create index ml_docsindex on ml_docs(doc_text) indextype is ctxsys.context
parameters ('lexer bid_lex');

create table ml_rules(
  rule_cat_id     number,
  rule_text       varchar2(4000),
  rule_confidence number
);

begin
  ctx_cls.train(
    index_name => 'ml_docsindex',
    docid      => 'doc_id',
    cattab     => 'ml_doc_categories',
    catdocid   => 'dc_doc_id',
    catid      => 'dc_category',
    restab     => 'ml_rules',
    rescatid   => 'rule_cat_id',
    resquery   => 'rule_text',
    resconfid  => 'rule_confidence'
  );
end;

create index rules_idx on ml_rules (rule_text) indextype is ctxsys.ctxrule;

set serveroutput on;

declare
   incoming_doc clob;
begin
   incoming_doc 
       := 'I have spent my entire life managing restaurants selling burgers';
   for c in 
     ( select distinct cd_description from ml_rules, ml_category_descriptions
       where cd_category = rule_cat_id
       and matches (rule_text, incoming_doc) > 0) loop
     dbms_output.put_line('CATEGORY: '||c.cd_description);
   end loop;
end;
```